# How to draw a shape that resizes with the form WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and would like to know what to use to get a shape like the image below:
[image]

I also wonder if it is possible that this design may follow the form's dimensions, ie, if the form is resized, the design is too.

In advance, thank you!

Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, C#, WPF Application

Comment: How are you using the image? are you looking for a custom window border or do you just want that drawn on

Comment: How are you drawing the shape? Using geometry?

Comment: I fail to understand why users continually come here to ask something that Google could (and has) answered many times previously: [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx). That's *really* not what this website is for. Ask here when you have a *real* problem... otherwise ask Google.

Comment: Sayse and Bob, my first question is just that, what to use to get to draw this shape?

Comment: Sheridan, have a little patience, not all people are born with full knowledge, a simple question for you may be to me a "real" problem, anyway thank you too!

Comment: @PauloBalbino we just expect you to do some _basic_ research before asking a question.

Comment: @RyanEmerle, I performed a search before, but in my country of origin, the answers are few and as I did not know where to start searching in another language, I decided to post here to have at least a start, now I will do more research on the responses obtained ! By posting here, hopefully at least be guided and not get upset for posting something simple for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw the shape you can use a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx). A path can draw any type of shape specified by its Data property. The Fill and Stroke defines the colors of the shape.

To "follow the form's dimensions" you can set the Stretch property to "Uniform". The shape will then scale accordingly to the window.

Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication57.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
      <Path Data="F1 M 0 0 800 0 800 30 200 30 150 60 0 60 0 0" 
            Fill="Yellow" 
            Stretch="Uniform" 
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="4"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Happy coding :-)

Best regards,
Casper Korshøj

Comment: Casper, exactly what I need, what object to use and how to resize, perfect! Thanks and keep it up, helping those who are not born with knowledge! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **Path** to get that shape and you can even use Blend to draw any shape, if you want just shapes.

```
   <Path Data="M200.125,197.375 L200.125,190.25 277.375,190.25 277.375,191.5 277.375,192.375 220,192.375 217.25,195.125 214.5625,197.8125 z" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8.562" Margin="200.125,190.25,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78.25" Fill="#FFF0F00C"/>
```

That should give you the Shape you wanted and in the comment mention above use that link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393%28v=vs.110%29.aspx